# abort .ajax request and stop downloading files

Tags: jquery, ajax

I apologize if this is a re-post, I can't figure it out though.  I'm loading a page full of images, and I would like to stop the download if the user navigates away before the images are downloaded.  I have the abort() working I think, but the files continue to download.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var jqXHR;
$('.buttons li#stop').click(function(){
    jqXHR.abort();
    alert('aborted');
}); 
$('.buttons li#start').click(function(){
    jqXHR = $.ajax({
    dataType:"html",
    url:"images.php",
    success: function(data){
        $('.pageContent').html(data);
    }
    });         
});
```

});

Comment: on a fast connection AJAX will have been completed a lot faster than user will hit a button. You won't be able to stop the image http requests

Comment: You are using an ASYNC ajax..   You can not stop the request which already sent to server..  You may have to send another ajax inside '$('.buttons li#stop').click' to stop downloading action in server...  hope this helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jqXHR could have already completed, and the HTML you get is already insert into .pageContent. The browser is downloading images specified in the HTML, so you can't stop it by aborting the jqXHR.

You can try set html of .pageContent to empty, but I don't know if this is going to work as you expected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jqXHR;
    $('.buttons li#stop').click(function(){
        jqXHR.abort();
        $('.pageContent').html(data);
        alert('aborted');
    }); 
    $('.buttons li#start').click(function(){
        jqXHR = $.ajax({
        dataType:"html",
        url:"images.php",
        success: function(data){
            $('.pageContent').html(data);
        }
        });         
    });     
});
```

Or you can just hit the Stop button of your browser.

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks.  Setting the html to empty does not seem to stop the downloads either.